# Does flushSync force repaint?

Tags: reactjs

my understanding is that `flushSync` does a synchronous force reflow but not a repaint of the screen. So in the following snippet (taken from [the github discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21)), we can get the correct style info based on the updated state value `c` after the first `flushSync` call, however, the change is not visible yet. React provides no way to repaint the screen. It only mutates the DOM and It's browsers that decide when to repaint. Is my understanding correct? Thank you!

```js
import { useState } from 'react'; 
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom'; 

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    flushSync(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    });
    // React has updated the DOM by now
    flushSync(() => {
       setFlag(f => !f);
    });
    // React has updated the DOM by now
   } 

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next</button>
      <h1 style={{ color: flag ? "blue" : "black" }}>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Update:**

@JaredSmith made a comment that browser will undoubtedly paint in between the two `flushSync`. I did an experiment to verify that but the experiment actually suggests that the browser will not paint between the two `flushSync`.  In the following code, I inserted a loop which runs for 20s after the first `flushSync`. What I see is that `val: 0` is first rendered, and then after 20s, `val: 2`. The intermediate `val: 1` is never painted to the screen. This experiment  indicates that there is no repaint between the two  `flushSync`.
Based on the experiment result, I suspect that the browser (Chrome) intentionally avoids repaint until a function completes its execution (even though I cannot find a spec for that).

```js
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(0);
  useEffect( ()=> {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.debug("first flushSync starts.");
      flushSync(setVal((v) => v + 1));

      console.debug('about to start loop');
      const st = Date.now();
      var et;
      var diff;
      do {
        et = Date.now();
        diff = Math.floor((et - st) / 1000);
      } while (diff < 20);

      console.debug("loop end");
      flushSync(setVal((v) => v + 1));

    });
    return;
  }, []);
  return (<div>
            val: { val }
          </div>);
}
```

Comment: "however, the change is not visible yet" this is wrong, the call to `setCounter` will trigger a rerender. "React provides no way to repaint the screen. It only mutates the DOM and browsers decide when to repaint" this is true but has no bearing on the question: the browser will undoubtedly paint in between the two renders. Will the user be able to see it? Almost certainly not. Preventing that is not what this is *for*, it's for when the second call relies on a *change to the DOM* from the first, which should be *exceedingly* rare, which is why they said that in the thread.

Comment: @JaredSmith: you said "the browser will undoubtedly paint in between the two renders".  what guarantees this? Is it defined somewhere in the browser spec? Thank you!

Comment: There's no guarantee about when the browser will paint. But understand: your JS code is moving in s--l--o--w m--o--t--i--o--n compared to the multithreaded C++ browser itself. Running your JS code is one tiny part of what it's doing. It will be painting the changes React pumps into the DOM *well* before the next tick of the JS event loop.